# Why can't classes in the same package see each other automagically?

Tags: java, groovy, package

Why is it that when I am running a Eclipse Groovy project, that the scripts aren't visible to each other in the same package?   Why do I have to explicity define the directory of the script engine.  Why doesn't ***new GroovyScriptEngine( "C:/Eclipse/workspace/Stack/src" )*** work?

```
package com.test
import groovy.lang.Binding
import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine
Binding binding = new Binding()
// explicitly defined path to where Hello.groovy script is located
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine( "C:/Eclipse/work/S/src/com/test" )
gse.run( "Hello.groovy", binding )
```

Another way that works is:

```
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine( [ './com/test' ] as String[] )
gse.run( "Hello.groovy", binding )
```

The error I get when I try to run with the script engine in the src dir is:

```
// project working directory is C:/Eclipse/work/S/src
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine( "C:/Eclipse/work/S/src" )
.....
Caught: groovy.util.ResourceException: 
    Cannot open URL: file:/C:/Eclipse/work/S/src/Hello.groovy
    at com.test.TestExample.run(TestExample.groovy:9)
```

This is a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970929/java-classes-in-same-package).

Comment: automatically or automagically ?

Comment: I hate the word automagically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In groovy as in java you have to seperate the concepts of source-folder and package.
The source folder in your case is "C:/Eclipse/work/S/src", the package is "com.test".

If you specify "C:/Eclipse/work/S/src" in GroovyScriptEngine, you need to fully specify the class (i.e. "com/test/Hello.groovy") , even though the calling class is in the same package.

Since "Hello.groovy" is in "C:/Eclipse/work/S/src/com/test/Hello.groovy" (I suppose),

```
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine( "C:/Eclipse/work/S/src" )
gse.run( "Hello.groovy", binding )
```

just isnt enough. You are missing the "com/test", so you either specify

```
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine( "C:/Eclipse/work/S/src/com/test" )
gse.run( "Hello.groovy", binding )
```

or

```
GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine( "C:/Eclipse/work/S/src" )
gse.run( "com/test/Hello.groovy", binding )
```

where i would consider the latter case "more correct".

Comment: Thanks for the help.   I was hoping that what I was seeing was unusual, but it seems that its not.